# Problem with tau function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Show that $\tau(n)^a$ is $o(n)$ (small $o$) for all $a$ real, with $\tau(n)$ the tau function (number of divisors of n).

I have not completed the demonstration of this.

Comment: It's more conventional to write it as $\tau(n) = O(n^{\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. What have you tried?

Comment: One idea that i had is to show that the series determined for this is converget, this will force to the limit stated to be zero.

Comment: it's in Hardy and Wright.

Comment: You can make a self-answer, if you feel that it's not the same as the reference you had.

Answer (score 2):

Not widely known, it is a result of Nicolas and Robin that 
$$  \tau(n) \leq n^{\left( \frac{1.066018678...}{\log \log n} \right)}  $$
with the constant $1.066...$ chosen for equality at $$ n= 6983776800, \; \; \tau(n) = 2304  $$ and nowhere else.

Canadian Mathematical Bulletin, volume 26, number 4, December 1983, pages 485-92: Majorations explicites pour le nombre de diviseurs de $N.$

There are also three slightly stronger results in Robin's 1983 dissertation at Limoge. 
With equality at a number $n$ near $6.929 \cdot 10^{40},$
$$ \tau(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1.934850967971...}{\log \log n} \right)}   $$ 
Note that this gives a qualitative version of Wigert's theorem, Theorem 317 in Hardy and Wright, page 262 in the fifth edition. But Wigert did not just give an upper bound, he also said that $\limsup$ of the appropriate expression is $\log 2.$

well, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43103/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-highly-composite-numbers/43105#43105